# Whats are needs of grouping CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm learning CSS and I found this syntax to group multiple selectors:

```
element-1, element-2 {
    /* css declarations */
}
```

This means that the elements are in the same styling, so why don't we give them the same class? Is there any recommendations?

Comment: When you design non-simple websites you'll start to understand the reasoning. Basically you can use this idea to add properties to *existing* CSS rules, under certain conditions.

Comment: Its a preference or a developer's style of writing. You could write it as a class as well. Again it just depends on the scenario

Comment: _"so why don't we give them the same class?"_ What would be purpose of setting same `className` at different elements, if same results are returned without setting same `className` at elements? _"Is there any recommendations?"_ What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @guest271314: do you mean that giving the same `className` is an extra effort in writting?

Comment: in this case, below in our styles, these selectors have different properties! so, use the rule DRY (don't repeat yourself)!

Comment: @M_E In part, yes. If not necessary to to return expected result, what would be purpose of setting same `className` at different elements? Depends on what you are trying to achieve; if using element as selector did not return expected results.

Answer (score 2):

While there are probably many reasoning behind a general syntax decision, I could at least name one. Take the following example:

```
ul, li, p {
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

Sometimes when you are resetting styles across different elements, you can use `,`. You may group those using classes, but that would mean you need adding a class like `.no-padding` to each and every `ul`, `li`, `p`.

Not neat.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the CSS rules without group of selectors, but you can minimize your CSS code with these groups. See the following example:

```css
.one, .two {
  color:red;
}
.two {
  text-decoration:underline;
}

/** not optimized / no selector group */
.oneone {
  color:red;
}
.twotwo {
  color:red;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">Hello World #1</p>
<div class="two">Hello World #2</div>

<p class="oneone">Hello World #1</p>
<div class="twotwo">Hello World #2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another illustration to join the two already featured (by [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36736278/3536236) and [sebastianbrosch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36736251/3536236))

Say you have a class that sets some values for an HTML element:

```
.someClass {
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:#c00;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
}
```

And just suppose you have another element (`.someOtherElement`)which you want to have the same font-size as `someClass`, and the same colour, same padding but no border?

Option 1:
Write everything out twice:

```
.someClass {
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:#c00;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
} 
.someOtherElement {
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:#c00;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
}
```

**Option 2**: Don't write everything out twice:

```
.someClass, .someOtherElement {
    font-size:1.1rem;
    color:#c00;
    padding: 1vh 1vw;
} 
.someClass {
     border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

This more closely follows the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principles of programming and allows for immense flexibility, applying various rules to as many or as few identifiers as needed.